# ressio/lazy-load-xt: "disable auto initialization" seems not working

Tags: lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

It seems to be impossible to disable auto initialization:
Both 
    $.lazyLoadXT.autoInit=false;

AND

```
$.extend($.lazyLoadXT, {
autoInit:  false
});
```

do not prevent lazy loading.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cvlug/16f5h1mn/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the code specified in the [docs](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt#advanced-initialization):

```
$.lazyLoadXT.autoInit=false;
```

That didn't work for our project, which loads jQuery and lazyLoadXT sandboxed within a Require.js object. LazyLoadXT appears to be trying to access jQuery as window.$ which, but that is not where jQuery is located when it's loaded inside Require.js.

We ended up making a fork of lazyLoad that addresses this issue, by removing their jQuery wrapper and wrapping their code inside a Require.js define statement. Now it's all the same scope. Maybe it will be useful:
https://github.com/Sitetheory/lazy-load-xt